# multiple models in a view .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using Asp.net core 2.2. In A view I want to add two models and loop through them but I dont know how to do it.
This is my **ProductCategory** domain model

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my **Product** domain model

```
public class Product
{
     public int ProductID { get; set; }
     public string ProductName { get; set; }
     public int ProductCategoryID{ get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryID")]
     public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add them in A view (or a view and multiple partial view) like this:[image: MyView architecture]

**And as [this article](https://ardalis.com/your-api-and-view-models-should-not-reference-domain-models) suggests, I don't want to use domain models in a view model/view.** How do you solve this? At first I thought it's a good idea to first MyView loads ProductCategories and then different partial views load products. But in that way I should hard code model of each partial. I want to make it dynamic so when an admin adds a category and its products, the controller adds them dynamicly to MyView. 
If u have a problem with understanding my idea just inform me to provide u needed information as u wish. Cause I don't know what is necessary information for this post.

So When i'm designing the **MyView** I can do something like this (just a mockett and abstract idea of what I want to do.)

```
@foreach(var p in model.ProductCategory)
{
    <div>
       <h1>p.ProductTypeName</h1>
        @foreach(var c in model.Product)
        { 
           c.ProductName
        }

    </div>


}
```

Comment: First A list of ProductCategories then a list of Each productCtegories' products in front of them.

Comment: To have database dependencies in your model will make it very difficult to seperate application layers. Just as hint.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to use domain models in a view model/view

Create a view model or DTO for this purpose and use the same in your view. As a good practice you should keep an isolation between your actual domain entity/model and the model(s) used for your views to display data.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get; set;}
  public ProductCategory ProductCategory {get; set;} 
}
```

Posted example is just a simple one. You can customize this to your need (I mean the specific fields you want to display) and have only those in your view model. Not only that, now you can use *DataAnnotations* in your view model like

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name="My Products")]
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get; set;}
  public ProductCategory ProductCategory {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: Yet u are using domain models (Product and ProductCategory) in the MyViewModel. The linked article says "Your API and View Models Should Not Reference Domain Models"

Comment: @ArianShahalami see updated answer. Linked answer doesn't mean not using the domain entity at all rather not using it directly for view purpose

Comment: Using namespaces, I usually have Dbos.Product and Dtos.Product or ViewModels.Product, they are what they are, Product, just for different purposes

Comment: ok it's good idea. How about making `ProductViewModel` and `ProductCategory ViewModel` and pass them to `MyViewModel` rather than passing the domain? Is that acceptable? I mean is it strandard?

Comment: @ArianShahalami Yes you can as long it results in a easier and maintainable and make more sense; I won't too much worry about standard

Answer (score 1):

You need a `ViewModel` like the following:

```cs
public class MyPageProductVM 
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
}
public class MyPageProductCategoryVM 
{
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }

    public IList<MyPageProductVM> { get; set; }
}
```

Your view can now use `IList<MyPageProductCategoryVM>` as the model. You could ofcourse go ahead and create another `MyPageVM`  class to contain the list and any additional fields, and make the view use `MyPageVM` as the model.

I believe this is not what you're after, but for completeness, another option is to denormalize the domain models:

```
public class MyPageProductVM 
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }

    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

---

You can use a library like AutoMapper or Mapster to map the domain models with the view models.

Comment: The second solution u provided is better I think. Because I've read somewhere that ViewModel is a model which provide everything a view needs. In the first solution `MyPageProductVM` is not a ViewModel because we dont use it in a view. it's something like DTO. Am I right?

Comment: @ArianShahalami ViewModels *are* DTOs (used to transfer data to the view). So `MyPageProductVM` is a DTO and so is `MyPageProductCategoryVM`. Ideally, you want your ViewModels to reflect the way the data is laid out in the view. So I'd go with the first option based on the image you shared. If the view duplicates the `ProductCategoryName`/`ProductCategoryID` field, I'd go with option 2.